# Android:: Keeping Network Connection alive after destroying Activity

Tags: java, android

```
I am trying to create a service that manages my network communication on my app but everytime I destroy my activity my server crashes and I believe this is I am still waiting to receive on the server end. 
My understanding of the service is it runs until you stop it so I feel my channel should be open until I close. I know it'd take a lot of battery life but, I'm trying to understand the concept of the service very well before I optimize my battery life. Here is what I have



    public class SampleService extends Service {
        public final static String TAG = SampleService.class.getName();
        private HandlerThread nThread;
        private NetworkHandler nHandler;
        private Looper nLooper;
        private Socket socket;
        private ObjectInputStream is;
        private ObjectOutputStream os;
        .......
            .........
        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate(); Sample Created");
            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.185", 6060);
                        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
                        is = new ObjectInputStream(new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate(): UnknownHostException error", e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate(): IOException error", e);
                    }
                }

            }).start();
            nThread = new HandlerThread("Network Thread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            nThread.start();
            nLooper = nThread.getLooper();
            nHandler = new NetworkHandler(nLooper);
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate(); Service setup");
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service started "+ startId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
            // stopped, so return sticky.
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate(); Sample Destroyed");
        }

And Activity





      public class ServiceActivity extends Activity {
            Intent service;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);
                service = new Intent(this, SampleService.class);
                startService(service);
            }

            ........
    ........
            }

I don't really have much added there just this...





    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_service, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause()
        {
            super.onPause();
    //      stopService(service);
        }



I decided to add my server to make things clear...



public class CloudServer{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private List<Socket>clientSockets;

    public static final String TAG = CloudServer.class.getName();

    public CloudServer(int port) throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        clientSockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();

        System.out.println("Listening to clients on port "+ port);
        for(;;) // infinite loop
        {
            Socket s;
            String id = generateSessionId();
            clientSockets.add(s = serverSocket.accept());
            System.out.println("Connection was established");
            if(sessionId.size() > 0)
            {
                Set<String>ids = sessionId.keySet();
                for(String session: ids)
                {
                    while(id.equals(session))
                        id = generateSessionId();

                }
            }
            sessionId.put(id, s);
            new Thread(new Worker(s, id)).start();
        }
........
    }



    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

        new CloudServer(6060);
    }


.........
}
```

and here is the worker for Server

```
package com.dcloud.server.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class Worker implements Runnable{
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream is;
    private ObjectOutputStream os;
    private boolean running;
    public static final String TAG = Worker.class.getName();
    private Message in;

    private String sessionId;
    public Worker(Socket s, String id) throws IOException
    {
        this.socket = s;
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        sessionId = id;
        running = true;
    }

    public String getSessionId()
    {
        return sessionId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(running)
        {
            try {

                while((in = (Message) is.readObject())!= null){
                    if(in.getRequest() == Event.Request.REGISTER)
                    {
                        //debugging purposes
                        CloudServer.writeToFile(TAG + ": got into the Register request");
                        new Thread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                try {
                                    String message = in.getMessage(); 
                                    registerUser(message);
                                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (SAXException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (SQLException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }

                    else if(in.getRequest() == Event.Request.LOGIN)
                    {
                        CloudServer.writeToFile(TAG + ": got into the login request");
                        new Thread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                try {
                                    String message = in.getMessage();
                                    handleLogin(message);
                                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (SAXException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (SQLException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }

                    else if(in.getRequest() == Event.Request.DISCONNECT)
                    {
                        running = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            is.close();
            os.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

........
.......
//  I don't think this affects anything...

}
```

I get and IO Exception and Its because of the while((in = is.readObject)!= null) line
which would suggest that my app is trying to break out of connection when I destroy the activity. That's how I interpreted it but according the Service documentation on the android website, the service should be alive until I stop it explicitly myself...

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.dcloud.server.service.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What other code do you have in your `Activity`? For example `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`?

Comment: I didn't really implement them... I put up the rest of the code

Comment: OK, so your `onPause()` method has `stopService(service);` commented out. Are you saying that even with it commented out your `Service` is still terminating?

Comment: So i just put up my server and I don't think there is much wrong with it (but I could be wrong) I feel the socket connection on my app breaks that's why I get the runtime error.... but I don't see why that should happen since I comment out the "stopService(service)"; portion

Comment: You mention you "destroy" your `Activity`. How are you doing this? Just with the `BACK` button or by calling `finish()` or by some other way?

Comment: I am using the android 4.0.2. When you swipe the activity from the task bar

Answer (score 0):

If you phone goes to sleep (screen goes dark), you won't have a network connection. If you want to stay connected you need to prevent the phone from sleeping by acquiring a WakeLock. This of course comes with the penalty of using battery, so you should release it as soon as you are done with your network operation(s).

Comment: Okay. Thanks and I am guessing this is the same mentality for destroying an activity?

Comment: Destroying an activity doesn't necessarily stop the internet connection. However if you don't interact it with, the phone will eventually go to sleep and the connection will be cut off.

Comment: yeah but in my case the phone does not go to sleep. All I do is destroy the activity and I get a runtime error in my server....

Comment: By 'server' you probably mean 'service'? Do post the full stack trace.

Comment: No by server I mean the server my android application connects to... I just post the stack trace..

Comment: Well, your `SampleService` doesn't seem to do anything in it's `run()` method, so when it exits the thread is done. You may also want to start whatever threads you need in `onStartCommand()`. It doesn't seem that you problem is related to your activity being destroyed, get your server-client communication working before proceeding.

Comment: The client server communication worked quite well when I tested it. I am just trying to rewrite the code using a service. Another reason I believe it works is because I do not have the problem until I destroy the activity (swipe the activity away from active tasks). That shouldn't happen because at that point, the service is still alive so my connection should be alive as well.
A good example would be a messenger application. I could destroy the activity but the service is still alive because once I receive a message, I am notified of its arrival.

Comment: I think somehow after I destroy/delete the task, the socket connection somehow tries to get close or something.. I don't know if I'm making any sense?

Comment: Ah, this is very different. If you swipe it away Android will kill your process, which includes your service. If you want to test the activity going in the background, simply press the home button or switch to another activity. Additionally, even a service doesn't usually run forever. If you want it to, you need to make it a foreground service (with an ongoing notification), but that might not be a good idea battery-wise, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks. That sheds light on the issue. Just out of curiosity is there a specific method called when I swipe the activity away, cause I would have to deal with that then... onstop(), onpause() is called everytime I push back or home key as well....

Comment: Even if you don't swipe it out, the system can destroy it at any time without warning so you should be able to handle that.

Comment: So basically this way the 'safest' way to communicate is to connect to the Server only when you want to make a request?

Comment: The safest way is to be able handle dropped connections, timeouts, etc. as well as your service being restarted by saving stated and reconnecting as needed.

Comment: can you please post a sample so I'd have a better idea of what you're saying

Comment: You need a robust protocol and a robust implementation. If you don't want to re-invent the wheel, just stick with HTTP/HTTPS.